# how to make popup characters swipe not clicked in custom android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I am developing custom keyboard in android and I have some popup characters but they are in a different style, so I want to change their style for example make the background white, and I want to make the popup characters swipe not clickable, see the images, when long press on the "." character the ".com .net .org" will appear

when long press on "."

[image: when long press on "."]

this should appear, see it's background color is different than the original keyboard

[image: this should appear, see it's background color is different than the original keyboard]

thanks in advance.